# network unstable connection

Tags: networking, xubuntu, 15.04

My Xubuntu 15.04 has no stable ethernet connection. My hardware

```
Hardware:CPU~Dual core Intel Core2 Duo E6550 (-MCP-) 
         speed~2336 MHz (max) Kernel~3.19.0-30-generic x86_64 
         Up~11:56 
         Mem~2158.0/3951.9MB 
         Procs~172 
         Client~Shell 

 Network:Card~Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
         driver~r8169

inxi~2.2.16
```

my config (~$: ifconfig)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr **:**:**:**:**:** 
          inet addr:***.***.***.***  Bcast:***.***.***.***  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2426194 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1386565 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3265229597 (3.2 GB)  TX bytes:147159020 (147.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:25184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3672387 (3.6 MB)  TX bytes:3672387 (3.6 MB)
```

my router:

```
Model :     Edimax BR6228nS/BR6228nC
 Up time :      Running Time 0day:05:30:13
 Hardware Version :     Rev. A
 Boot Code Version :    1.0
 Runtime Code Version :     1.28
```

status ipv6:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

my provider does not support ipv6 protocol and i disabled it. Twisted pair is not damaged. Windows7(in dual boot) haven't this problem. In my wife notebook (dualboot Xub/Win) a similar situation. 
**Question**
how to testing this malfunction? what should I do?

- *sorry of my English - i'm Ukrainian*

Comment: so basically eth0 --> router --> internet?

Comment: @AizuddinZali yes : eth0 --> router --> internet

Comment: and there is NAT between internal and internet? If so, then you need to focus between router and eth0. It doesnt matter what your ISP settings are. Do you see anything strange in `dmesg` output? any kernel taint?

Comment: what can i  see *"strange"*? where i can read about *"NAT"*? I am newbie in Linux OS

Comment: NAT is not linux specific, its networking tehcnology and IEEE standard. just type `dmesg` in the terminal when this issue happend. from dmesg you will see kernel logs about any driver that hiccup.

Comment: @Aizuddin http://pastebin.com/HwyKCh9j - Please see this output of my *dmesg*

Comment: I dont see any kernel taint (except for NVIDIA) in the dmesg. The information below saying that the pysical connection was down  and I believed something is not right with your router. In this case you need more information on the network, you need to snif the network using `Wireshark` or equivalent.   

`[   19.913307] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down`
`[   19.913321] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down`

Comment: thanks for the help! But the problem was in the router. For 1 hour of his ping (192.168.2.1) - 51% packet loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the router,and I decided to buy a new